# Prove $\dim(\operatorname{Im}T)=\dim(\operatorname{Im}T')$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ Of finite-dimensional vector spaces. Is there an easy way to see that prove $\dim(\operatorname{Im}T)=\dim(\operatorname{Im}T')$ for $T'$ being the dual map defined by $T':W' \rightarrow V'$, $f \rightarrow f \circ T$? I am not been able to see why this is true.

Comment: What is the difference between $Im$ and $im$?

Comment: @Gary None, sorry, I will fix that

Comment: Are $V,W$ known to be finite-dimensional?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes

Comment: Other answers on other posts (slightly different notation, of course). See e.g.  [Prove the rank of $f$ is equal to the rank of $f^*$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295012/prove-the-rank-of-f-is-equal-to-the-rank-of-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At heart:

> **Lemma:** For $k=\dim(\operatorname{Im}T),$ there exists a basis $w_1,\dots,w_m$ of $W$ and a basis Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $V$ such that $Tv_i=w_i$ for $1\leq i\leq k$ and $Tv_i=0$ for $i>k.$

This is relatively easy to prove. See the outline below.

Then if $w_i’\in W’$ is defined as $w_i’(w_j)=\delta_{ij},$ then $$(T’w_i’)(v_j)=w_i’(Tv_j)=\begin{cases}0&j>k\\\delta_{ij}&j\leq k\end{cases}$$

So $T’(w_i’)=v_i’$ if $i\leq k$ and $T’(w_i’)=0$ if $i>k.$

From here, we can quickly show that $\dim\operatorname{Im}(T’)=k.$ Basically, the image of $T’$ is generated by $v_1’,\dots,v_k’.$

---

**Outline of how to construct the bases of the Lemma.**

1. Pick $w_1,\dots,w_k$ as a basis of $\operatorname{Im}T.$
2. Extend to a full basis $w_1,\dots,w_m$ of $W.$
3. Pick any $v_1,\dots,v_k$ such that $Tv_i=w_i.$ Show these are linearly independent.
4. Show you can extend $v_i$ to basis $v_1,\dots,v_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n$ with $Tv_i=0$ for $i>k.$

That last step is the slightly tricky part. But if $Tv_j\neq0$ for $j>k,$ we can write $Tv_j=\sum_{i=1}^k a_iw_i$ for scalars $a_i$ then replace $v_j$ with:
$$u_j=v_j-\sum_{i=1}^ka_iv_i$$ and still have a basis. And $Tu_j=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Lax has a very insightful proof in his book Linear Algebra and Its Applications. The “four subspaces theorem” (which is beloved by Gilbert Strang) can be generalized to a general finite dimensional vector space using annihilators as a substitute for orthogonal complements. The range of $T’$ is the annihilator of the null space of $T$. So $\text{dim } N(T) + \text{dim } R(T’) = n$. But we also know that $\text{dim } N(T) + \text{dim } R(T) = n$. It follows that $\text{dim } R(T) = \text{dim } R(T’)$.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why dim ()+dim (′)=?

Comment: If $W$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$, and $W^\circ$ is the annihilator of $W$, then $\text{dim } W + \text{dim } W^\circ = n$. This generalizes the fact that in a finite dimensional inner product space we have $\text{dim } W + \text{dim } W^\perp = n$.

Comment: But then we would need $dim (Ker T)^{\circ} = dim Im T'$, right? Why is this true?

Comment: The generalized “four subspaces theorem” (presented in chapter 2 of Lax, I believe) tells us that $N(T)^\circ = R(T’)$. This generalizes the familiar “four subspaces theorem” which tells us that if $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ then $N(A)^\perp = R(A^T)$.